# Creating a commodity price index chart

Tags: plotting, data

I am stuck at creating a commodity price index chart like this:

[image: IndexChartGoals]

The chart is supposed to show the developments of multiple shares presuming they had a value of 100 at day one. I have created a data set that includes the 100 in the first row and the growth rates for 2985 days for 36 companies (columns).

How can I calculate the artificial stock price for every day and company. I wrote the following code, but it doesn't incorporate a variable that would function as a loop-index.

```
PrepedLogReturn = 1 + LogReturn;
IndexDataBase = Map[Prepend[#, 100] &, Transpose[PrepedLogReturn]];
TransIndexData = Transpose[IndexDataBase];
IndexData$$ = x = TransIndexData[[1, All]]; 
x *= TransIndexData[[2, All]]
```

(I have attached the outputs as pictures)

[image: TransIndexData]
[image: IndexData$$]

Comment: What is the definition of `LogReturn`?

Comment: Is the problem creating the data (price of stock for 36 companies over 2985 days) or plotting it ?

Comment: LogReturn is the name I gave the list that contains the daily log return to which I added the +1 to simplify the calculation later.  The problem is to create the data, like I tried for the first row (IndexData$$), just for all rows at once.